# Occasional error while deleting files

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;

NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *files = [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:cachePath error:nil];

for (NSString *path in files)
{
    NSString *fullPath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
    BOOL removeSuccess = [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
    if (!removeSuccess)
    {
        return error;
    }
}
```

the code above occasionally gives cocoa error 513 which is about permissions. I download files  from internet placing in caches directory. Do I have to explicitly set some permissions or do something else? Why the error happens only sometimes? It never happens on 6.0/7.0, but happens sometimes on 7.1.

Comment: I think you should create dedicated directory for your data in cache and not delete all content of cache

Comment: Do you have any prove of that theory, reference where it says I can't delete files in root caches folder?

Comment: No, is only my guess, but if you look at content in cache folder you can see a lot of files that created not by your app directly.

Comment: I think you are right... creating subfolder addressed the issue. You can answer to question so I can accept it.

Comment: Maybe you can get the attribute of the file when error occur using `[NSFileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:error:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I write in comment I guess the problem related to deleting some system files that not directly own by your app and should not be deleted.

for example how looks `Cache` folder in basic app with one `UIWebView`
[image]

To avoid strange errors is better to create dedicated folder inside `Library/Caches` and delete content inside respected to your needs

Comment: I guess I was deleting something that was not created by me. Somehow I thought Caches folder dedicated to me and nobody else can write there.